# Proper Workflow for video upload utilizing ASP.NET MVC and Encoding.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone with experience using cloud encoding services like Encoding.com with asp.net MVC point me in the right direction workflow wise?

I will be storing my videos in Amazon S3 so I would like to avoid forcing the user to upload to my web server only to immediately be pushed to S3.

Encoding.com has made this uploader script available [here](http://www.encoding.com/how_can_i_use_your_.net_uploader_tool)

I am wondering if this is the proper start to the workflow and where would I go from here? I would imagine I could take this result and call their API to begin the processing.

Just looking for general info/help on the workflow as a whole and what to show the user while all of this is taking place.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.